# Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings not working for HTTPS

Tags: vba, google-maps, google-api, runtime

I have a lookup function in Excel (2010) that maps to a google for getting zip code data. I have some cells with formulas to look up against the XML data remotely: I have one cell named ZipCode. The code below updates city and state based on a newly typed zip code.

Here is the code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

   If Target.Row = [ZipCode].Row And Target.Column = [ZipCode].Column Then
     Dim Zip As String: Zip = [ZipCode].Value

     If Len(Zip) <> 5 Or Not IsNumeric(Zip) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid zip code!", vbCritical, "Invalid Zip"
        Exit Sub
     End If

    Dim Map As XmlMap
    Set Map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1)
    Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml/?address=" & Zip & "&sensor=false"
    Map.DataBinding.Refresh
  End If

 End Sub
```

The routine fails at:
`Map.DataBinding.LoadSettings "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml/?address=" & Zip & "&sensor=false"`

with the following runtime error

> runtime error -214721376 (80041020) The system could not locate the object specified.

I am not having much luck in understanding why it is failing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is incorrect:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml/?address=
```

The URL should be:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=
```

(also the sensor parameter is no longer required)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert...but I know the video you are watching and I got this error. You aren't specifying to excel the proper xml source. Your code is perfect as per the video, but my guess is that you messing up here:

> `Set Map = ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps(1)`

This may not be referring to the correct xmlmap. I would suggest deleting the source files and reloading the xml map again.